# Отправка SMTP из контроллера Laravel

Tags: laravel

Парни, хочу из контроллера сделать отправку письма, помогите-

```
$reciever = 'poluchatel@mailx.com';
$name = 'MySite';
$email = 'no-reply@mysite.com';
$title = 'Уведомление';
$content = 'Сообщаем Вам, шо вы молодец!';
```

\Mail::send(['name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'title' => $title, 'content' => $content], function ($message) {

```
        $message->to('$reciever')->subject('Subject of the message!');
    });       
   }
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail

Comment: того что мне нужно не увидел там. подождем еще ответов.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail#sending-mail

Answer (score 0):

```
Mail::raw('Текст письма', function($message)
{
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');
});
```

сделал как в доке.